# Inner divs to expand the outer div with scroll horizontally

Tags: css

How to make the child divs to display all in one line inside outer div and not fall to second line?
The outer div width should be fixed so the scrollbar should be visible so we can scroll to see all inner divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/pkbkY/

```
<style type="text/css">
    .child
    {
        width: 100px;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<div style="width: 500px; overflow: scroll;">
    <div class="child">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    a
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    a
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    a
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    a
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    a
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    a
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pkbkY/1/

```css
#scroll_container {
    width: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.child {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

If you need the gaps to be gone, the easiest solution is to remove the whitespace between the child elements: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pkbkY/2/